# Create Login page and generate logs in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, logging, authentication

I am a total newbie.
I create a website with 2 pages

1. Update data (update.aspx)
2. Add data to database (add.aspx)

I want to create login page before they can access this pages.
Even if they tried accessing by typing direct url like : www.example.com/add.aspx
they should not be allowed

And secondly,
I want to generate txt log files when they click update or add button
example 
User: abc updated current field in databse on (time and date)

I hope you guys help me out. :)

am using visual studio 2012 and SQL Server

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx, http://nlog-project.org, http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Comment: Thanks David for the links :) will check out

Answer (score 0):

As I understand of your question, you want to activate authentication in your project. In this way there is a great article about Authentication in ASP.NET that is suitable for newbies.

[ASP.NET authentication and authorization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98950/ASP-NET-authentication-and-authorization)

The "Forms Authentication" section in the article can fulfill you expectation.

Also, there are some logging libraries like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), [Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647183.aspx) that are advanced and have lots of facilities, but for starting I recommend you reading [Create Simple Error Log Files using ASP.NET and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2344/Create-Simple-Error-Log-Files-using-ASP-NET-and-C). With a bit change in the code you can log the text that you've mentioned.

Comment: For login I used Create user wizard and for generating logs I am thinking of implementing NLOG. Thanks.

Comment: Nope..I am using  Create Simple Error Log Files using ASP.NET and C#.  :) Thanks